# Issue using rn-nodeify in React-native project

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cryptojs, web3js

I am developing a mobile app using React native, which involves an interaction with [Meta1.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meta1js)

and Problem is RN does not support core Node.js modules, so I had to install `react-native-crypto`, `react-native-randombytes`, `rn-nodeify` and run `./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install` I actually followed this [docs](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify)

[but I end-up with that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTHTF.jpg)

I also tried to install node, clean the cache, delete watchman, and none of that worked for me, and when I run `yarn ios` the app crash (build failed)

This is the package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install fs,dgram,process,path,console --hack",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.1",
    "assert": "^1.5.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.1.4",
    "buffer": "^4.9.2",
    "console-browserify": "^1.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.2.0",
    "https-browserify": "0.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "punycode": "^1.4.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.7.0",
    "react-native-os": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.1",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.2.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "^0.10.31",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.4.2",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  }
}
```

this my first time to ask a question on stack overflow and I hope someone will tell me what to do?